# How to prevent a closing </option> tag from being removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I want to achieve like this

```
<select id="funsports" name="funsports">
   <option value="">sports</option>
   <option value="football">football</option>
   <option value="tennis">tennis</option>
</select>
```

But when I am saving widget it forcibly removes the closing tag at the end. When I am using this type of options in blogger widget I am getting problem like this.

How we can forcibly close with `</option>` tag at the end? Any way to do with jQuery or JavaScript or we can achieve through HTML and CSS only.

```
<select id="fungames" name="fungames">
  <option value="" />games
  <option value="roadrash" />roadrash
  <option value="gta" />gta
</select>
```

Comment: Why do you feel this is a problem? It's valid HTML (as shown in [Rahul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38184305/82548), below).

Comment: David Thomas i dont know according to my template in blogge or what but when i save it with </option> again if i open editor it wont shows i want to close the </option> for my project some values are not taking as i said above. any other proven methods to do those

Comment: In your question you *show* a value is missing, but you don't *say* (anywhere in your question) that that is the problem you wish to solve. But it's more or less irrelevant, since without a `value` the text of the `<option>` is used as the value when the parent `<form>` is submitted; so if you're able you'd probably have an easier time removing the `value` attributes from the `<option>` elements. Although I don't understand why this widget is "*forcibly [removing] the closing tag.*"

Comment: @DavidThomas  first of all i want to know different way of closing the <option> tag because i will tell the reason in my website design the </option> once entered it does not shows when i reopen the editor. This cause damages to the whole code

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that Blogger appears to use `XHTML`. User-provided HTML has to be post-processed to guarantee that the server delivers valid XML.

Comment: we must know what happens between the stage where the `select` element has "closed" `option` tags and when it seems to have not. the answer is directly related to your specific code which you have not mentioned here. This doesn't happen by itself of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, as others have stated, not an actual problem, but if you really want that last  tag, just use jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/tu3wpzsj/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').append('</option>');
    $('option').each(function(i){
        if(i!=0) $(this).before('</option>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html) says:

> **Tag omission**
>
> An option element must have a start tag. ***An option element’s end tag
>   may be omitted if the option element is immediately followed by
>   another option element, or if it is immediately followed by an
>   optgroup element, or if there is no more content in the parent
>   element.***

Comment: but when i save with </option> tag and if i reopen the widget in html it wont displays close tag what should i do for this

Comment: The question is not asking if the HTML is valid. It's asking how to keep the closing tag.

Comment: @Michael: but this answer is implying - though admittedly not clearly stating - that the closing tag is optional, is not required and it not being there is not a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: yeah @Michael_B is right i want to know different ways to close the option tag thats it